# Network Analysis Layer in ArcGIS Mobile Map Cache

Tags: layers, network-analyst, mobile, arcgis-mobile, mapcache

Does anyone know how to extract a Network Analysis Layer into an ArcGIS Mobile Map Cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the Webhelp for creating Mobile Maps, You will see that Network Analysis Layers are not supported.

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=6673&pid=6671&topicname=Design_and_create_Mobile_maps

And here is the documentation from [v10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/help/007v/007v00000008000000.htm)